# Local installation of gcc on CentOS

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, centos, local

I would like to know if it is possible to install gcc as a "local installation" on my home directory?  Thanks!

I am running CentOS 5.5 and exploring the possibility of installing gcc 4.2.* in my home directory btw.

~Susanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Ans : You need a sysadmin access if you are installing any app in Linux but there are ways to tweak it like -

Using sudo

```
$sudo make install
```

Using a prefix

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/install
```

Creating a private RPM database and installing from it (though for gcc I doubt it should work)
ref - http://www.nordugrid.org/documents/rpm_for_everybody.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sameer! Just one doubt, the methods you had mentioned above, are 3 different ways to get what I want done right? OR are they interrelated? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try this: yum install gcc
If you're going to compile from source you'll also want to have kernel-devel installed...
yum install kernel-devel

Comment: Hi Coder, thanks for your reply. If I use yum to install, wouldn't it install for all users (as in, in the /usr/bin or something directory)? Is it possible to install gcc in the ~ (home directory)?